Trying to use the arm-none-eabi compiler-toolchain on MacOS using an M processor
I installed my compiler using brew:
brew install --cask gcc-arm-embedded

I implemented a small hello world test.c file:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!\\n");
   return 0;
}

But when I try to compile it, i only receive the following error messages:
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x28): undefined reference to `_exit'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_lseek'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_read'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x24): undefined reference to `_write'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-abort.o): in function `abort':
abort.c:(.text.abort+0x10): undefined reference to `_exit'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_kill'
/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/13.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(libc_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x4): undefined reference to `_getpid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea how to fix this issue?

You have no SDK...
